# flutter does not install on my raspberry pi

Tags: flutter, dart, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, raspberry-pi-os

I:
1.installed raspberry pi OS on raspberry pi 400. Then:
2.installed snapd. Then:
3.installed snap-store. Then:
4.installed flutter. Then:
5.I ran this command: flutter doctor

when I ran "flutter doctor" this error occurs:

```
Downloading Linux arm64 Dart SDK from Flutter engine f3496a7185c2e12fa895dbac553ec7ee8968b874...
% Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current
Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed
100 193 100 193 0 0 299 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 299
[/home/ali/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk-linux-arm64.zip]
End-of-central-directory signature not found. Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of /home/ali/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk-linux-arm64.zip or
/home/ali/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk-linux-arm64.zip.zip, and cannot find /home/ali/snap/flutter/common/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk-linux-arm64.zip.ZIP, period.
```

It appears that the downloaded file is corrupt; please try again.
If this problem persists, please report the problem at:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=1_activation.yml

I tried installing flutter on raspberry pi OS on raspberry pi 400. But it did not install.